# Are 2 CSS3 opacity transitions, 1 for each div, possible on layered absolute divs?

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a double opacity hover effect on 2 layered divs with `position:absolute` on top of an image link.

1 to fade `div.hovertitle`, 1 to appear `div.hovercontent`.

This is my attempt:http://jsfiddle.net/Ajucreazy/UR43Y/

Is it possible to trigger them both with 1 `selector:hover {}` code? Or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the hover classes to the wrapping element, the `article` in your case. http://jsfiddle.net/UR43Y/1/